# How to Use CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer on large data set(Train,Dev,Test)?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

Implement each of the following feature templates using only
CountVectorizer​ and​ TfIdTransformer. I have train, dev, test data.

Here is my sample train data:

```
Train_dataset = ['This is country of srilanka','This  was very much', ' hi bro how are you']
```

a. Represent only word occurrences with binary values (​baseline​).
b. Remove stop words (these are the most common words in the English language).
c. Represent term frequencies of words.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, just make a dataframe from your python list. 
Then make a custom function using **[nltk](https://www.nltk.org/)** library which have corpus of all **[stopwords](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/removing-stop-words-nltk-python/)**, remove if you have some irrelevant tags there and preprocess your data.
Sample Code:

```
stop = set(stopwords.words('english')) #set of stopwords
Now you can check iterating over your data and remove the stopwords
```

Then let say you have cleaned your text after that do just like below for count & tfidf

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train_data['CleanedText'])
X_test = count_vect.transform(X_test_data['CleanedText'])
print(X_train.shape) 
print(X_test.shape)
```

Note : X_train, X_test are the transformed vectorizer after countvectorizer

Same with the tfidf,

```
tf_idf_vect = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train = tf_idf_vect.fit_transform(X_train_data['CleanedText'])
X_test = tf_idf_vect.transform(X_test_data['CleanedText'])
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
```

Note : X_train, X_test are the transformed vectorizer after tfidf vectorizer

> More you can find my implementation [here](https://github.com/abhikumar22/Amazon-Fine-Food-Reviews-Analysis/blob/master/Amazon%20Fine%20Food%20KNN/amazon_fine_food_knn_3_abhikumar22.ipynb)

I hope this helps...Thanks :)

Comment: hi, i need TfIdTransformer. not the TfidfVectorizer.

Comment: it will work same for the TfIdTransformer......more you can read here  https://kavita-ganesan.com/tfidftransformer-tfidfvectorizer-usage-differences/#.XdzKvOgzb4Y